# How to find if an element of a has_many association is included in another one?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a Twitter like application where a `User` can follow an other `User` through a `Connection` model I have problems to display if a `Follower` gets followed back by the `@user`.

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :last_name, :string

    has_many :follower_connections, MyApp.Connection, foreign_key: :followee_id
    has_many :followers, through: [:follower_connections, :follower]

    has_many :followee_connections, MyApp.Connection, foreign_key: :follower_id
    has_many :followees, through: [:followee_connections, :followee]
[...]
```

**web/models/connection.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Connection do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "connections" do
    belongs_to :follower, MyApp.User
    belongs_to :followee, MyApp.User
[...]
```

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user =
    Repo.get!(User, id)
    |> Repo.preload([:followers, :followees,
                     :followee_connections,
                     :follower_connections])
  conn
  |> assign(:user, user)
  |> render("show.html")
end
[...]
```

**web/templates/user/show.html.eex**

```elixir
<ul>
<%= for connection <- @user.follower_connections do %>
    <li>
      <%= connection.follower.last_name %> 
      <%= if connection.followee.???include?(????) do %>
        (You follow him/her back.)
      <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

How can I find out if `connection.follower` is part of or included in  `@user.followees`?

Bonus question: Where is this in the Ecto documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
<%= if Enum.any?(@user.followee_connections, fn(x) -> x.followee_id == connection.follower_id end) do %>
  (You follow him/her back.)  
<% end %>
```

There is probably a better way it can get you started.

Also I think that preloading all those followers and connections can consume a lot of RAM, for example if the person has tens of thousands of followers. I believe it may make sense to rewrite those to queries with limits, so it would load only user's 50 followers or whatever, not all of them each time.